# Expand * in select sqloracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way/shortcut we could use to replace `*` with all the column names in table while using `select * from table as t1`
For eg., `*` would be automatically replaced into `select t1.column1,t2.column2,.....,(etc.) from table as t1`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you notice sqwiggly line below the star symbol?

Comment: No there were no sqwiggly lines below star symbol, that's what I was wondering why, how to enable that sqwiggly line @Tegiri Nenashi

Comment: [7 Ways to Avoid SELECT * FROM Queries in SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/11/7-ways-to-avoid-select-from-queries-in-sql-developer/)

Comment: Typically SQL clients have some kind of auto-completion feature to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is unlikely that the table named "table" exists in your schema. Second, the AS alias syntax is wrong in oracle dialect. Here is screenshot how it works:

[image: Here is how it works]